# Intra company Transfer to Canada : Company Requirements

Tags: working-visas, canada, british-columbia

I have been acting as a CEO of a small India-based company which I started with a partner in 2017. The tax returns have been filed every year and it is an active company.

The other partner moved to Canada and registered the company there in Canada in 2020 December but has not proactively worked on expanding the business there yet, Was able to get a few customers onboarded over the year. Sales and marketing are not this partner's forte thus it's been proposed that I move to Canada to expand the business.

My question is:

1. Will a company registered in 2020 in Canada be considered a start-up there so that the application won't be rejected due to the lack of a lease for the company's physical address? It is currently registered at the partner's residential address.
2. How much funds do we need to have in the Canadian Company's account in order to meet the company's eligibility criteria?
3. Any criteria for the foreign country (back in India) other than it needing to be active?

Comment: Is the Canadian-registered company a subsidiary of the Indian-based company?

Comment: @Traveller Not sure. But it was mentioned somewhere that the company operates in a different country as well. Do you know how can that be verified?

Comment: A Canadian company needs to have a qualifying relationship with the foreign company (parent, subsidiary, branch, or affiliate company). Your partner in Canada should be able to tell you